# Structuring Relationships in Firebase

Tags: firebase, relationship, denormalization

I've got two items in my Firebase: `providers` and `services`, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure and build relationships using Firebase's recommended flattened architecture approach.

My data looks something like this:

```
{
  "services" : {
    "hip_replacement" : {
      "title" : "Hip Replacement"
    }
  },

  "providers" : {
    "the_blue_hospital" : {
      "title" : "The Blue Hospital"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to link these two items together so that if you were to visit the Hip Replacement page, The Blue Hospital would show up underneath it, if you were to visit The Blue Hospital page, Hip Replacement would show up underneath that. A two-way relationship, essentially.

What would be the best way to structure something like this? I was thinking along the following lines:

```
{
  "services": {
    "hip_replacement": {
      "title": "Hip Replacement",
      "providers": {
        "the_blue_hospital": true,
        "the_red_hospital": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "providers": {
    "the_blue_hospital": {
      "title": "The Blue Hospital",
    },
    "the_red_hospital": {...
    },
    "the_green_hospital": {...
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or a more elegant solution? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems doable, you could certainly do worse :).  How much data do you expect on each service and provider dimension?  How frequently would create/delete operations be performed as opposed to reads?

Comment: @JamesWing A decent amount of data (10-12) on each dimension, no deeper than 2-3 levels though. Why do you ask? Is there a better way if I'm dealing with large amounts of data?

Comment: I was thinking the opposite, of having the client load all the data from a "join" table of sorts.  If there are hundreds of small records, that might be very doable.

Comment: Not sure what a "join" table is, can you elaborate on this? The plan is to keep these dimensions in sync.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with joined data in Firebase is that you optimize for certain read or update use cases at the expense of others.  In your sample above, creating or deleting a relationship between services and providers requires two separate updates to each "table".  There's really nothing wrong with that, but it's not the only way to go.

For a modestly sized data set, you could have a "join table" that maps services to providers, similar to what might be done in the relational DB world.  The data might look something like this:

```
{
  "services": {
    "hip_replacement": {}
  },
  "providers": {
    "the_blue_hospital": {...},
    "the_red_hospital": {...},
    "the_green_hospital": {...}
  },
  "serviceProviders": {
    "-JqD5JX0RUDTXsu7Ok3R": {
      "provider": "the_blue_hospital",
      "service": "hip_replacement"
  }
    "-JqDoKfyJqPkQlCXDvFM": {
      "provider": "the_green_hospital",
      "service": "hip_replacement"
  }
    "-JbE7Ji_JRz2bHgBdMWQ": {
      "provider": "the_blue_hospital",
      "service": "hip_replacement"
  }
}
```

There are pros and cons of this approach:

*Pro*

- Easy to add mappings in one place
- Easy to delete mappings in one place
- Flexible options to reformat the data for display, beyond the context of a single provider or service, such as an index.

*Con*

- You have load the whole data set.  Firebase doesn't let you filter within a key, clients have to load the whole list, then filter in memory.  I suspect this will work fine for hundreds of records, anyways, maybe for low thousands.
- You have to do some client work to filter the list for display and merge it with the actual service and provider data.  Again, if the data set isn't too big, underscore/lodash groupBy() can make short work of this.

You should consider:

- How much updating and deleting will you do?
- Is the join information really that simple?  Would you need more records (display names, prices, etc.) that make maintenance on the join table more complicated than I suggested?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Firebase doesn't let you filter without a key." Could you not simply do `orderByChild('service').equalTo('hip_replacement')` or an equivalent op using [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)?

Comment: You're right, when the serviceProvider items are as simple as shown above, you would be able do that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Let's say I was to take this approach, would it be hard to maintain updates between data in `providers/services` and data in `serviceProviders`? Let's say "the_blue_hospital" was renamed "the_sky_blue_hospital", would I still have to update in two places?

Comment: If the key field changed, yes.  If you modeled that as a "displayName" or other non-key field, no.

Comment: Hmm, you've given me something to think about. This is my first stab at something like this, and it's dawned on me that a database should be elegant in the way it's structured. I'd like to find the most elegant approach and take it.

Comment: @JamesWing Sorry if it seems like I'm asking so many questions. I'm just trying to understand this a little more. With your approach, when looking at say `-JqD5JX0RUDTXsu7Ok3R`, would I need to match its `provider` against the `providers` `.key()` to obtain more info on that provider? Just wondering if this is performant or not...

Comment: No problem.  To display a "Hip Replacement" service page you would have to 1) load the service data, 2) load the list of service providers, then 3) load each of the providers in that list.  For reasonable numbers of service/providers, I don't think that's going to be a problem.  You could consider pre-loading or caching some or all of the data on the client if the data volume is not large.