# Android Firebase database - Multiple foreign keys and relational data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to Firebase DB and I am having difficulty getting into the more complex concepts into code.

I am aiming to avoid multi-path updates and so I am normalising all complex object types. I have used the UID from the Firebase Auth system as the key to identify a user.

[image: example database]

I have looked around and found many simple examples of using Android Firebase DB, but I would like to get an example of a more complex operation. In particular, to get a list of all shared objects that have been shared by friends where the friend status is ACCEPTED.

Regards

Comment: Have you seen: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905280/structuring-relationships-in-firebase

Comment: @MorrisonChang Hi Morrison, yes, i've seen it. I realized that it would take multiple path updates to make an alteration, and that was mentioned in my above post. I am trying to achieve this using a join concept. The fan out approach is a valid approach but I am eager to ensure each data object is isolated to guarantee that state properties are never duplicated.

Comment: I would have tried a 'Friend_Accepted' as its own table (each state as its own table). Not sure if that would satisfy your requirement. Something else to look into: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/blob/master/src/NormalizedCollection/README.md

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang - How would that satisfy my requirement of having a working example of joining of complex data without data fanning in Firebase on Android exactly?

Comment: I think the key/value pair nature of Firebase means you can't avoid data fanning and the related multiple path updates. Your constraints may make Firebase a poor choice and you should be looking at traditional SQL based datastore if that is the case.